# How to use "until" grammatically correct

Tags: grammar

Which one is grammatically correct ?

> 1. I waited there until he **had come**.
> 2. I waited there until he **came**.

Or this case:

> I must try going to bed earlier  until I **finished/finish/have finished** the course. Which one is correct? Is there any rule?

What's the rule?

Comment: Aren't both correct? First is perfect tense, second is indefinite.

Comment: I've now made the question completed. Would you please answer this.

Comment: Will you please tell us which grammar book you use for studying verb tenses? What did you find there related to the verbs in your question? Any grammar book will give the rules that you need in the previous examples.

Comment: Sure, these are scripts from Grammar for IELTS Cambridge. Whenever I see a tense I would ask myself whether the other one is correct or not. That's my problem.

Comment: In the first examples, your dilemma is not with "until" but with the tenses **Past Perfect** and **Past Simple**

Answer (score 2):

> "I must try going to bed earlier until I finish the course."

I chose the indefinite tense one, because you are waiting for the course to be finished.
*"Have finished"* can be used too, as it would be showing something that has to be completed in the present.
*"I finished"* is totally wrong, as it is past, and you have not finished the course yet.

Similarly, for the first answer both forms of past tense are correct.